# My css wont apply to my html how do i fix this problem?

Tags: html, css

Noob here, My Css wont apply to my Html. Im learning Selectors in Css and my code wont run.I already linked it to my html file but i cant seem to find the problem . [The universal selector i wrote so i could change the background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGQn.png)[What i wrote to link my Css file to my html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMpl6.png)

```
<link rel="Style" href="Name of file">
```

```
*{
   background-color: black;
}
```

I wrote down the link for my css and html to connect but it wont work.

Comment: It's `<link rel="stylesheet">`, not `"Style"`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHH IT WORKS NOWW

Comment: Voting to close because the problem was caused by a typo.

Answer (score -1):

i think that you forgot to include the type argument in the tag

try with:

```
 <link href="file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="Text/css" media="all"  title="file"/>
```

here it is better explained with many examples, if it can be useful: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: w3schools.com is not an authoritative resource - in future please use links to authoritative sources such as W3.org and WHATWG's technical standards/specifications, or browser vendor-operated sites like MDN and web.dev.

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional and, in this particular case, pointless. The problem is the typo that Dai pointed out. (Note that "The problem was caused by a typo" is a standard close reason so this question shouldn't be answered)